Movie from 2005-2010; widow dude; cars falling into water with headlights on
It may be a movie around 2005-2010. The plot is something about a guy that gets widowed and then moves to an island to restart life. There is a bridge that links the island to the land.
There is an impressive scene when several cars fall from the bridge into the water with an underwater take where you can see the cars sinking with the headlights on. Very dramatic.
In some parts in the movie, the phone on the guy's house rings and he believes that it is his wife trying to communicate to him.
I really would like to watch this movie again but I have no clue about the title or cast!

Sounds like The Mothman Prophecies from 2002 with 
    Richard Gere (though I don't think it's an island).

John Klein is involved in a car accident with his wife, but while he is unharmed, his wife mentions a moth shaped creature appearing. After her death, John begins to investigate the secrets behind this mentioned Mothman. It takes him to a small town of Point Pleasant, West Virginia, where he discovers a connection with the same problem. Here he meets Connie Mills, while he continues to unravel the mystery of what the Mothman really is.

Near the end, a bridge collapses and several cars fall into the water with their headlights on, which is depicted at length underwater. And I'm pretty sure the hero gets some strange phone calls which he suspects are from his late wife. You can see the bridge scene here, and here's the trailer:




Walt, you nailed it! That's exactly the movie and I never would recall the title. I remembered that it was with a famous star but I couldn't see Richard Gere and kept thinking in Kevin Costner (maybe because the Dragonfly movie that has a similar plot). Thank you so much, I have pursuiting this movie for a couple years now and was starting to think that I was imagining it! :)
